# Overclock and Underclock graphics card using Registry Keys

Tags: graphics-card, overclocking, underclock

Is it possible to use the registry to over clock or under clock a graphics card?

Comment: Consider that the clock settings aren't necessarily stored in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used to be able to do the Coolbits registry hack with older Nvidia drivers, but not anymore.  You can, however, use the [Nvidia System Tools](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia_system_tools_6.06.html) to expand the Nvidia control panel with overclocking tools.  This is the only way (without the use of third party, non-Nvidia software) to overclock your video card now.

Comment: Yes, but the Nvidia System Tools can't recognize my Nvidia graphics card, so it can't launch.